# How to use WHERE IN with an empty value in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am trying create a dynamic dashboard in grafana 7.4.x with variables that can be selected. This works with one exception. In case there is no value selected, the value is empty and will result in a MySQL (5.7.32) error.

```
$value = 1,2,3
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE ID IN ( ${test:csv} )
```

empty value results in :

```
$value = ''
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE ID IN (  )
```

How can this query be rewriten in order to not result in an error but simply ignore this one where statement (as there are many ANDs)

Comment: Yes but 0 will result in 0 results. This is an optional filter as one of many filters.

Comment: If you're building the `WHERE` clause dynamically from multiple filters, check if the list is empty before adding `ID IN (...)` to it.

Comment: How? IF (${test:csv} , 0,1) will also result in: IF (  , 0, 1)

Comment: Not in SQL, in the programming language you're using to create the query.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. This is not possible, it is Grafana as a front end where you only can add MySQL as a Query.

Comment: How are you doing all the other filters optionally?

Comment: It is always the same problem. I posted this minimal example to illustrate it. One can only add the SQL query and put variables as placeholders for values that get selected in a drop down. If none is selected the variable is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in place of `IN`, as that function will take an empty string:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, '$value')
```

Comment: YES! Thank you, that worked. I am surprised how much there is to learn about SQL

Comment: @merlin indeed - the standard isn't too bad but there are *so* many DBMS specific features like this one.

Comment: isnt `FIND_IN_SET` made specify for `SET` type in mysql?

Comment: @Seti in theory yes, but the way it works means that it can be used to find values in a comma separated list

Comment: yes it is, but it would be VERY VERY slow on numerical fields as it will make check on each row for the ID of numberical and string to number convertion - isint it?

Comment: It will be slower than using `IN`, definitely, because of that. Not very very though, the conversion isn't that slow. Regardless, with OPs restrictions on what they can do, I believe this is the only solution that will work for them.

Comment: im sure there is another option - probably graphana is used wrongly, or there is something you can use from grapahana that will use real null and map correctly to coalesce or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
where id in (coalesce($value, 0))
```

but im not sure this will work with grafana query builder - but worth a try

Comment: Good approach, but this does neither work in MySQL native without Grafana: IN (coalesce (, 0) )

Comment: you are left without any value, that is not null